# Virtual host with ProxyPassReverse and preserve link

Tags: virtual, host, raspbian

I'm hosting a web site using Apache and i'd like to create a virtual host like freepbx like mydomain.com/freepbx.  freepbx runs on port 7000, and when I create the virtual host, and i pont to a sub link, the browser automatically redirects to my main site.  Is there a way to create a system where I can substitute the links?  Right now I'm using

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
</Proxy>


ProxyPass /freepbx/ 192.168.1.109:7000/
ProxyHTMLURLMap 192.168.1.109:7000 /freepbx
ProxyPassReverse /freepbx/ 192.168.1.109:7000/
    <Location />
   Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
```

but this doesn't work